# Unity Slider decrease as timer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, slider, countdowntimer

I'm trying to make a countdown timer but using a Unity Slider instead of text but I've ran across a few issues. So my current code is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour {
    //public Text timeText;

    public float startingTime = 100.0f; 
    public Slider Timer;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Timer = GetComponent<Slider> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        startingTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        Timer.value = startingTime;

        if (startingTime <= 0)
        {       
            startingTime = 0;
            Application.LoadLevel ("GameOver");         
        }
    }
}
```

This code works if I were to replace the slider with the text but not vice versa. My second issue is when I attach this code to my player and link the slider from the hierarchy, it disappears when I start the game.

Last issue is when I try to add an On Value Changed, I can link it to my player to get the functions from the code but from doing my research there isn't really anything I can link it to since I only have start and update. Scrollbars can use private voids and receive the dynamic float that way but I haven't been able to yet with Sliders

Example:
[On Change Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EZp7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work on the slider you say, you need to pass the max value as 100 on the slider component, or it uses 1 until the value gets between 0 and 1.

A UI item has to be under a Canvas to be rendered, so attaching it to your player makes it discarded from rendering. You can put the Canvas with the slider as child under the player object. But I would keep the canvas separated for clarity(POV).

The picture you added shows that you passed an object, but now you need to assign a method. Click the No Function and it will display all the available methods.

Comment: Ok the timer/slider works, its just when I play the game now the slider which I dragged to my script will disappear, but if I place it there whilst the game is playing it'll do exactly what I want it to. But for now it keeps disappearing

Comment: Fixed it, added the script to the Slider itself and linked it to itself. Thanks